# Exercise 11 of section 3.2.2(The art of computer programming)

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I'm asking about its part a.

> a) If $f(z),\space a(z),\space b(z)$ are polynomials with integer coefficients, let
> us write $a(z)\equiv b(z) (\operatorname{mod} f(z)\space and\space m)$
> if $a(z) = b(z) + f(z)u(z) + mv(z)$. Prove that the following statement
> holds when $p^e>2$ (p prime) , $f(0)=1$:
>
> *If $z^\lambda \equiv 1 (\operatorname{mod} f(z)\space and\space p^{e})$ and $z^\lambda \not\equiv 1 (\operatorname{mod} f(z)\space
> and\space p^{e+1})$ then $z^{p\lambda} \equiv 1 (\operatorname{mod}
> f(z)\space and\space p^{e+1})\space but\space z^{p\lambda} \not\equiv  
> 1 (\operatorname{mod} f(z)\space and\space p^{e+2})$*

Here's my reasoning:
We have $z^\lambda$ has the form of
$$f(z)u(z) + p^ev(z) + 1$$
where $p^{e+1}|f(z)u(z),f(z)|p^ev(z)$ and $v(z)\not\equiv 0(\operatorname{mod} p)$  **(*)**
Or we can just simplify it as: $z^\lambda = Z + 1$, where Z is a multiple of $f(z)$ and $p^e$ but not $p^{e+1}$'s one.
So:$$z^{p\lambda} = 1+{p\choose 1}Z+{p\choose 2}Z^2+...$$
$z^{p\lambda}-1$ is certainly divisable by f(z). Also, we can see that ${p\choose k}Z^k(1\leqslant k\leqslant p-1)$ is a multiple of $p^{e+1}$ and $p^{e+2}|Z^p$(due to the fact $p^e>2$,$p^{pe}|Z^p$ implies $p^{e+2}|Z^p$). We now can conclude:
$$z^{p\lambda} \equiv 1 (\operatorname{mod}
f(z)\space and\space p^{e+1})$$

Next, it's easy to establish: $p^{e+2}|p^{(e+1)k}$,where $k\geqslant$ 2. And that shows:
$$z^{p\lambda} \equiv 1 + p^{e+1}v(z) (\operatorname{mod} p^{e+2}\space and\space f(z))$$
Due to **(*)**,$1+ p^{e+1}v(z) \not\equiv 1(\operatorname{mod} p^{e+2})$, completing the proof

---

My proof is based on the answer of excercise 11. And the difference between it and mine makes me confused.

> If $p^{e+1}v(z) \equiv 0 (\operatorname{mod} f(z)\space and\space p^{e+2})$, there must exist $a(z)$ and $b(z)$ such that $p^{e+1}(v(z) +pa(z)) = f(z)b(z)$.
> Since $f(0)=1$, this implies $p^{e+1}|b(z)$(by Guass's lemma 4.6.1G); hence $v(z) \equiv 0 (\operatorname{mod} f(z)\space and\space p)$, a contradiction.

So, my questions are:
*1. Why is the above argument necessary?*
*2. Is the Gauss's lemma 4.6.1G the one in wikipedia?*

Comment: It is common to add a space after punctuation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have $z^\lambda$ has the form of
>   $$f(z)u(z) + p^ev(z) + 1$$
>   where $p^{e+1}\mid f(z)u(z),f(z)\mid p^ev(z)$ and $v(z)\not\equiv 0\pmod p\ $  **(*)**

You misunderstood the definition of $a(z)\equiv b(z)\pmod {f(z)\text { and }m}$. If $z^\lambda \equiv 1 \pmod{ f(z)\text{ and }p^{e}}$, then $$z^\lambda=1 + f(z)u(z) + p^ev(z)$$
for some $u(z), v(z)$. There is no further requirement on $u(z)$ and $v(z)$. It is incorrect to deduce $p^{e+1}\mid f(z)u(z)$. It is incorrect to deduce $f(z)\mid p^ev(z)$.

However, if we also have $z^\lambda \not\equiv 1 \pmod{ f(z)\text{ and }p^{e+1}}$, then we must have $v(z) \not\equiv 1 \pmod{ f(z)\text{ and }p}.$

---

> Why is the above argument necessary?

Now that you can understand the notation correctly, you can figure it out by yourself.

---

> Is the Gauss's lemma 4.6.1G the one in Wikipedia?

Yes, lemma 4.6.1G in the book is the same as [the Gauss's lemma on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)).

Comment: As i understand, Gauss's lemma is about irreducibility of a polynomial. It also points out the definition of **primitive polynomials** which i think it is enough to follow the proof. Due to $f(0)=1$,$f(z)$ should be a primitive polynomial with its constant equals 1. So, $p^{e+1}$ relatively prime to $f(z)$,leading to $p^{e+1}|b(z)$. Do i misunderstand again?

Comment: You got it. As shown on that Wikipedia article, $\Bbb Z[x]$ is a unique factorization domain (UFD) because of $\Bbb Z$ is a UFD.